# Flutter - Pub failed to rename directory because access was denied

Tags: flutter, dart

I have installed flutter 2 on my machine, and since this morning I have been receiving this error, when I try to give flutter pub get, in my terminal, or simply flutter doctor. I found several solutions on the internet but I don't know what it can be, and none of them solved my problem. I saw it on one of the sites that may be conflicting with antivirus, but I installed my new one yesterday, and it started to give error only today.

> flutter doctor
> Pub failed to rename directory because access was denied.
> This may be caused by a virus scanner or having a file
> in the directory open in another application.
> Running "flutter pub get" in flutter_tools...
> pub get failed (1; in the directory open in another application.)

Comment: https://github.com/dart-lang/pub/issues/1798

Comment: I already entered this link, but I was unable to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

There were GitHub issues that was filed before relating to this. There were no proper solutions to this, instead you can try some solutions that was mentioned in the following issue tickets:

- https://github.com/dart-lang/pub/issues/1798
- https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16100

You can try one of the solution mentioned in [this GitHub thread](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16100#issuecomment-403934886):

Try to run `flutter pub cache repair`.

There is another ticket that is still open for the troubleshooting to be added in the Flutter documentation for reference of everyone. And to be considered as the universal solution for this problem.